# Visual basic Kinect

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to set the value of the right hand joint to label but the value remains zero .

Label2.Text = handright.Position.X.ToString & "," & handright.Position.Y.ToString

the value of X and Y is single

is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that there are actual values in handRight.Position, this should work:

`Label2.Text = String.Format("{0}.{1}", handRight.Position.X, handRight.Position.Y)`